# Blank Named Property in jQuery Object

Tags: jquery, .net, csv

I am working on a CSV functionality for my .net application, and created a dynamic CSV importer that generates a datatable based on the object keys and data parsed through.

My issue is that when I am parsing the data, one of the example CSV's that I took from employees here has a few columns in the spreadsheet empty. So when I import it, and I debug the application and look at the data, I see this:

= "",
PART NUM = "12345",
...

The property name is a literal blank, I am not sure how to detect it and remove it via code. Any advice?

Since I know the layout of this particular example CSV, I can basically just skip the column that it is trying to load, but if I want some form of dynamic feel to it, I want to try and detect it programmatically and remove it before it creates the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if an element is empty in JQuery like this:

```
if (element === null || element === '' || typeof element === 'undefined')
{
    // do something
}
```

or...

```
if ($('.element').is(':empty'))
{
    // do something
}
```